# Is safe to use row_number() over (order by null) as a rownum alternative in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, row-number, rownum

I did some testing and it seems that row_number() over (order by null) could be used as an alternative to oracle's rownum pseudocolumn

```
select rownum, i.* from (
    select row_number() over (order by null) as rnum, i.*
    from c_invoice i
    order by i.dateinvoiced desc
) i;
```

Is this behavior by design or is just a coincidence?

Comment: If this is for pagination: which Oracle version are you using? In Oracle 12 you can use `fetch first n rows` instead

Comment: 11g so I can't use the new "top n" clause

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend it.  There is no guarantee that the `order by null` is going to respect the outer `order by`, although in practice the optimizer might do this.

Instead, you can safely do:

```
select rownum, i.*
from (select row_number() over (order by i.dateinvoiced desc) as rnum, i.*
      from c_invoice i
      order by i.dateinvoiced desc
     ) i;
```

You can check the query execution plans, but I suspect that the `row_number()` might add a slight bit of overhead.

Comment: The problem is that I need to implement pagination for a random sql and it's very complicated to move the order by clause into row_number (no aliases & column indexes allowed). Also, the reason I'm trying to force row_number() usage is that rownum is quite slow due to full scans

Comment: @IonuțU . . . I think `row_number()` will have performance worse than `rownum`.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `desc` in the `over` clause too?

Comment: @IonuțU - `rownum` shouldn't itself be causing a full scan, it operates on the result set late in the processing. If it's having to do a full scan to order the results and then pick out the rows for that page, then `row_number()` will do the same really? I would  expect `rownum`'s stop-check optimisations to be better in that case, at least for early pages.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Not for all queries. I tested a few complicated SQLs with rownum & row_number() and it seems that in certain cases rownum performance is really bad